# iPhone - UIWebView multiple locks

Tags: iphone

I receive the following error message in my debugger console:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x7400460: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
```

This occurs when I:

1. Load an UIViewController
2. Load an UIWebView from within this UIViewController
3. Then I push a second UIViewController from the first UIViewController
4. Load a second UIWebView from within the second UIViewController

I believe this has something to do with access to the UIWebView resource, but I´m really not sure.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this has to be a iphone simulator bug.

Will file a bug report to Apple.

Comment: This occurs on my iPod touch too.

Comment: v4.3 seems to be ok.. v5.0 seems to be buggy :(

Answer (score 0):

Is your first webview still loading when you push the second? I think you should be able to have multiple webviews onscreen simultaneously, but you might want to try calling -stopLoading on the first webview before pushing the second.