# Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now

Tags: xcode, ipad, locks

I'm getting the following error in output window of Xcode:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x9644290: Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now...
1   _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv
2   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
3   __CFRunLoopDoObservers
4   __CFRunLoopRun
5   CFRunLoopRunSpecific
6   CFRunLoopRunInMode
7   _ZL12RunWebThreadPv
8   _pthread_start
9   thread_start*
```

I've found the following posts: [Multiple locks on web thread not allowed! Please file a bug. Crashing now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037407/multiple-locks-on-web-thread-not-allowed-please-file-a-bug-crashing-now) & [iPhone - UIWebView multiple locks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735414/iphone-uiwebview-multiple-locks)

But, I'm not too sure the problem is related to the simulator as I'm using iPad 5.1 Simulator and also I've tested on an iPad device, and it crashes on the device as well?

I've figured out if I comment out a line which reloads a UITableView instance, the problem doesn't occur, however I need this line of code as it refreshes the listing I have shown.

```
//[listingTable reloadData];
```

Any ideas or assistance with this problem will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-do the way I created an object which was added to an NSArray used in the UITableView which stopped this error from happening.